# clear timeout after trigger click

Tags: javascript, jquery

If class triggered run another function only once and clear Timeout. I am using Firefox.

**Expecting**

```
var i = setInterval(function() {
if $('[style*="display: inline;"]').click();
   function start timeout() {
     document.querySelector('.body_inside_inside_once_').click()
        clearTimeout();
    }, 200); 
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Obligatory java != javascript comment.

Comment: Also, you have multiple syntax errors and it's unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara you means 
$('[style*="display: inline;"]').click(); != document.querySelector('.body_inside_inside_once_').click()

Comment: What do you mean with class triggered? The click event? Why using jQuery selectors and JavaScript selectors mixed. This snippet is so full of errors. Please refactor and rephrase your question. PS: whatever browser you use should be of no concern.

Answer (score 0):

Your questions is not clear ,and contains syntax error but for rough idea...The following code might help you to clearTimeout upon clicking a HTML element.

```
var i = setInterval(function() { 
   function start timeout() { 
           // Operation
}}, 1000);

document.querySelector('.body_inside_inside_once_').click(function(){
        clearInterval(i);
 });
```

Comment: hello this is not working see

var i = setInterval(function() {
  
   ` if ($('#body_inside_headercounter').css('display') == 'none')
      {
        
          
         $('[style*="display: inline;"]').click();
 
        var i = setInterval(function() { 
       function start timeout() { 
        // Operation
        document.querySelector('.body_inside_inside_once_').click()
      }}, 1000);
   document.querySelector('.body_inside_inside_once_').click(function(){
clearTimeout(i);
     
 });
        

   
      }`